# PHP-Date Matching, DataBaseDate with CurrentDayDate

Tags: php, calendar, zend-framework2

I have made a calendar in zend-framework2, and i want to show a specific event on a specific date, onto the calendar. This is the picture of calendar.
[image]

I want to set an if condition, that if `true` will show the event on the Calendar.

This is what i have tried yet...

```
<?php if($this->activity['activityCreated'] == $running_day):?>

    <p>hello</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

`$running_day` is the current day, and it's code is,

```
$running_day = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year));
```

So how do I match/compare database date with `$running_day` date?

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->activity['activityCreated'])` give you?

Comment: good idea, i was just thinking to try it, give me Null, which means activityCreated has no value, but why? and tnkx

Comment: No way for me to know that without seeing how you assign `$this->activity`. I'm sure you can further debug this from here.

Comment: yeah i think, thnkx

Comment: so the condition is correct, i assume?

Comment: The condition is syntactically correct. Whether or not it will do what you expect is another matter entirely. It's unclear why you assign `$running_day` as `date('w')` since that only gives you a numeric value of the day of the week (_0 for Sunday through 6 for Saturday_). I somehow doubt that you expect `$this->activity['activityCreated']` to have such a value. Code only shows me what it ___will___ do, not necessarily what you ___intended___ for it to do.

Comment: i was thinking to change w later, but for now  $activity has no data, wonder why, checking it out, and thnkx again for pointing out 'w'.

Comment: just got it, if i pick the values inside foreach, it will work,since i was not pointing the index of the array $activity. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135148/discussion-between-syed-muhammad-zulqarnain-and-sherif).